# How to process json data and put it into arrays in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a postgresql table with two columns. name VARCHAR(255) and notes JSON. A sample dataset might look like this:

```
| name      | notes                            |
|-----------|----------------------------------|
| 'anna'    | {'link_to': ['bob']}             |
| 'bob'     | {'link_to': ['anna', 'claudia']} |
| 'claudia' | {'link_to': []}                  |
```

Now I want to do two things.

1. put the list from the json at 'link_to' into another column called referrals_to (which must be of array VARCHAR type then). From my example:

   | name | notes | referrals_to |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 'anna' | {'link_to': ['bob']} | ['bob'] |
   | 'bob' | {'link_to': ['anna', 'claudia']} | ['anna', 'claudia'] |
   | 'claudia' | {'link_to': []} | [] |
2. create another column called referrals_from, where I want to store all names from which a name was referred. In my example:

   | name | notes | referrals_from |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 'anna' | {'link_to': ['bob']} | ['bob'] |
   | 'bob' | {'link_to': ['anna', 'claudia']} | ['anna'] |
   | 'claudia' | {'link_to': []} | ['bob'] |

How do I do this using postgresql queries? I could easily do it using python, but this would be slower than using postgresql directly, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `referrals_to` column can be done using the `->` operator to extract the array. For the `referrals_from` column I would use a scalar sub-select to collect all referring names into a single  column (a JSON array)

```
select name, 
       notes, 
       notes -> 'link_to' as referrals_to,
       (select jsonb_agg(name)
        from the_table t2
        where t2.name <> t1.name
        and t2.notes -> 'link_to' ? t1.name) as referrals_from
from the_table t1
;
```

The `?` operator tests if a JSON array contains a specific string. In this case it tests if the `link_to` array contains the name from the outer query.

[Online Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f3d04521ecf33f3a8c6f7109e715a341)

Assuming `name` is unique in your table you can use that query to update the new columns in the table:

```
update the_table 
   set referrals_to = notes -> 'link_to', 
       referrals_from = t.referrals_from
from (
  select t1.name, 
         (select jsonb_agg(name)
          from the_table t2
          where t2.name <> t1.name
          and t2.notes -> 'link_to' ? t1.name) as referrals_from
  from the_table t1
) t 
where t.name = the_table.name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I see no UPDATE command here, how can I store the referrals_to and referrals_from values in the respective columns?

Comment: @TomAtix: you didn't say anything about an UPDATE in the question. And you stated that your table only contains two columns

Comment: probably I wasn't 100% clear. My table initially had two columns, and I said I want to "create another column [with ALTER TABLE, I know how to do that] to store..." so I said I wanted to put that info in the columns. Anyways, would be great if you can update your answer to do that, thank you very much.

Comment: "create another column" could also mean "create another column in a query". See my edit. But the `referrals_to` makes no sense to me, as that is exactly the information that is already present in the `notes` column.

Comment: 1) thanks for the update. 2) I need the referrals_to field because I am applying some additional conditions I kept out of the question to keep it simple. 3) I needed to modify the set referrals_to statement a bit, because the format is different from a postgres array. 4) the referrals_from update statement works, I guess, apart from that I needed to cast the format of t2.notes -> 'link_to' to JSONB first, but it is highly inefficient, because it loops over the whole table over and over again for every entry. It doesn't complete after minutes for a table with a couple

Comment: of thousands entries. Therefore, I needed to solve it differently now, I loop through all rows of the table, and use a nested loop inside this one, which loops over all elements of the referrals_to array of each row and updates the respective other row (appends the name to the array in that row). This code completes after a few seconds.

Answer (score -1):

More or less what you described in your steps:

```
WItH cte AS (
  SELECT
    name,
    BTRIM(value:: text, '"') AS referrals
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        name,
        foo.notes:: json - > > 'link_to' AS link_to
      FROM
        foo
    ) a
    left JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements (a.link_to:: json) ON TRUE
)
SELECT
  a1.name,
  array_to_json(array_agg(a1.referrals))
FROM
  cte a1
  JOIN cte a2 ON a1.name = a2.referrals
GROUP BY
  a1.name
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I see no UPDATE command here, how can I store the referrals_to and referrals_from values in the respective columns?

Comment: @TomAtix You never mentioned any updates. And besides, it should be trivial to convert this into an update statement